# Merging cuesheet chapter halves into single track for an audiobook

Tags: cue-sheet, cue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a FLAC+cue from multiple FLAC files?](https://superuser.com/questions/432074/how-can-i-make-a-flaccue-from-multiple-flac-files)

I have an audiobook that I have ripped and I need some help constructing chapters. I have already made some cue sheets

```
TITLE "Bookname"
PERFORMER "the Author"

FILE "File1.FLAC" wave    ; 23971906.667 milliseconds
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "_Intro"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00   
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "CH 01"
    INDEX 01 24:15:50   
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "CH 02"
    INDEX 01 66:21:00   
  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "CH 03"
    INDEX 01 87:05:00
```

The audio book is in two files. The chapter at the end of the first file is continued in the second file.  However, the second file restates:

- The publisher
- Book Title
- List item
- Blah blah blah

I would like to  merge the two 'halves' of the chapter in one seamless track. The only way I can think to do this would be be:

1. Bulk cut down the tracks.
2. Drop the junk info into junk track
3. Continue the track listings as normal
4. Take the two "halves" of the target chapter and build a separate cue sheet for it.

I know there has to be an easier way. I am ok with making the 'junk' info a 'gap' or something.  These are are FLAC files that will be converted to MP3 for my phone and other potable devices.

I [have read](http://www.digital-inn.de/exact-audio-copy-english/16964-gap-cue-sheet-101-simple-tutorial-dummies-like-me.html) [the primers](http://home.scarlet.be/spb2267/gapscue/gapscue.htm) [on cue sheets](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?act=ST&f=20&t=4586), but I am just not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an automatic way to do this, but I would recommend downloading audacity and editing the audio files.

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is just free audio editing software but you can use anything.  Regardless of what you use I think that cutting the beginning of the second file with the redundant info out and then putting the two files back to-back and saving them to a WAV or FLAC or MP3.

If you do, do this you will have to manually edit the cuesheet to the time of each chapter, but that really shouldn't take more than 5 or so minutes.

Good luck!