# How can I make a FLAC+cue from multiple FLAC files?

Tags: audio, flac

I've tried Googling but can only find guides for the other way around.

I have a few flac files from an album, all properly tagged. I'd like to make them into a single flac file with a cuesheet automatically (ie not pasting into Audacity and making the Cue myself).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [shntool](http://www.etree.org/shnutils/shntool/), a multipurpose, multiformat command-line tool for manipulating lossless audio files.

```
shntool join -o flac *.flac
```

This generates a file `joined.flac` which contains the audio content of each of the files in `*.flac`. Note that you might want to specify the names of the FLAC files, rather than leaving it to `*.flac`. This lets you be sure that the files are joined in the correct order, and that no unwanted FLAC files get included.

```
shntool cue *.flac > joined.cue
```

This generates a CUE file `joined.cue`, a simple text file listing tracks and timings. The same caution about specifying names of the FLAC files applies. (If you are trying these commands in order, `joined.flac` will now be one of the files caught up in `*.flac`.)

Comment: Although note that this will include `joined.flac` in your cue file, which you probably do not want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `shntool`. I was looking to do the opposite (split a single file) and this was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

[Cuetools](http://www.cuetools.net/wiki/CUETools_Download) should let you do this - You can select the whole folder the files are in, and select "Embedded" for mode (embedded refers to album art, not the flac file. Select image+cue for a seperate album art image) and "Encode" For action. Select flac for filetype and libflake for the encoder

[image]

This will pop up a window that will have several sets of data for the cue sheet - the first one is based off your data, the others off freedb and other sites.

[image]

This should give you a single flac file with a cue file.

Comment: Thanks, I already have CueTools, so I don't know why I didn't try poking around in there first.

Is it common to use an embedded cuesheet? Is there not better support for having a separate one?

Comment: embedded dosen't refer to the cue sheet, it refers to album art

Answer (score 1):

I tried the foobar2000 route, but unfortunately, it didn't accurately print the INDEX variable for each track. I couldn't get the other solutions to work, either. I did a lot of trial and error (with some big assistance from ChatGPT) and wrote a bash script that does exactly this.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#if this doesn't work, you may need to install flac:
#sudo apt install flac
#written with significant help from ChatGPT

#INSTRUCTIONS: 1) Save this code as create_cue.sh
#                           2) Place it in the same folder as the .flac files you want to create a .cue sheet for
#                           3) Run the bash script (you may need to mark it as executable)
#                           4) Voila! Instant .cue file. Enjoy

# Get the first FLAC file in the directory
flac_file=$(ls *.flac | head -n 1)

# Get the header information from the FLAC file
PERFORMER=$(metaflac --show-tag=ARTIST "$flac_file" | cut -d= -f2)
TITLE=$(metaflac --show-tag=ALBUM "$flac_file" | cut -d= -f2)
DATE=$(metaflac --show-tag=DATE "$flac_file" | cut -d= -f2)
COMMENT=$(metaflac --show-tag=COMMENT "$flac_file" | cut -d= -f2)

# Set variables for the cue file
CUEFILE="$PERFORMER - $TITLE.cue"

# Initialize variables for cumulative time
HOURS=0
MINUTES=0
SECONDS=0

# Start writing cue file
echo "REM DATE $DATE" >> "$CUEFILE"
echo "REM COMMENT $COMMENT" >> "$CUEFILE"
echo "PERFORMER \"$PERFORMER\"" >> "$CUEFILE"
echo "TITLE \"$TITLE\"" >> "$CUEFILE"

# Loop through each flac file in the current directory
for flacfile in *.flac; do
    
    # Get track number, performer, and title from file tags
    TRACK=$(metaflac --show-tag=TRACKNUMBER "$flacfile" | sed 's/.*=//')
    PERFORMER=$(metaflac --show-tag=ARTIST "$flacfile" | sed 's/.*=//')
    TITLE=$(metaflac --show-tag=TITLE "$flacfile" | sed 's/.*=//')

    # Write track info to cue file
    printf "FILE \"$flacfile\" WAVE \n" >> "$CUEFILE"
    printf "  TRACK %02d AUDIO\n" "$TRACK" >> "$CUEFILE"
    printf "    TITLE \"%s\"\n" "$TITLE" >> "$CUEFILE"
    printf "    PERFORMER \"%s\"\n" "$PERFORMER" >> "$CUEFILE"
    printf "    INDEX 01 %02d:%02d:%02d\n" "$HOURS" "$MINUTES" "$SECONDS" >> "$CUEFILE"

    # Get length of track in seconds
    LENGTH=$(metaflac --show-total-samples "$flacfile")
    LENGTH=$((LENGTH/44100))

    # Update cumulative time
    SECONDS=$((SECONDS+LENGTH))
    if [ $SECONDS -ge 60 ]; then
        MINUTES=$((MINUTES+SECONDS/60))
        SECONDS=$((SECONDS%60))
    fi
    if [ $MINUTES -ge 60 ]; then
        HOURS=$((HOURS+MINUTES/60))
        MINUTES=$((MINUTES%60))
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. According to [the CueTools Wiki page](http://www.cuetools.net/wiki/CUETools_Settings#.288.29_Mode_.7Bsection.7D) "embedded" refers to the cue sheet. You have the option to embed it into the flac file, to create two separate flac+cue files, or to create different flacs for each track in the cue.  (Though I'm unaware of a software player which actually supports embedded cue sheets, you may know of one.)

Comment: [Max](http://sbooth.org/Max/) convertor supports embedded cue sheets.  It can convert FLAC (and other formats) to Apple Lossless and import files to iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Foobar2000 it can create single file with embedded cue sheet and can also embed art work and can play the resulting file as well
http://www.foobar2000.org/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.